# Ubuntu 14.04 apt-get dist-upgrade error on bcmwl-kernel-source

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

A dist-update I just did hung (froze) after printing line:

```
DKMS: install completed.
```

I had to close the terminal to kill process, and to carry on did

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
kill -15 THE-PID
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

The dpkg command above also hangs in same spot, but I did find through repeated efforts that I can Ctrl-C the dpkg command (after repeated lsof kill loops) and run other apt-get commands like update, check, clean, etc. but all result in a hand on same "DKMS: install completed." statement, and the associated out is always like below:

```
$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom
Kernel:  3.13.0-24-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
 - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
 - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
 - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.13.0-24-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-24-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
 - Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....
DKMS: install completed.
```

[Start Update @Pilot6 below] While there are no errors in the output above I do suspect that something is definitely out of wack with kernel setup. When I Ctrl-C out of another apt-get command (after doing another lsof, kill, dpkg iteration) I get output below which suggest configuration not correct. Still hesitant to reboot.

```
^Cdpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
Setting up fglrx-updates (2:15.200-0ubuntu0.5) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: error: unable to remove '/etc/ati': Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package fglrx-updates (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx-amdcccle updates:
 fglrx-amdcccle-updates depends on fglrx-updates; however:
  Package fglrx-updates is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fglrx-amdcccle-updates (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing: bcmwl-kernel-source
 fglrx-updates
 fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

I see bcmwl above which looks like code for my Broadcomm Wireless expansion card...

[End Update]
I dont think reboot is right answer here. Might not boot at all!
Gad Zooks! Any tips & tricks?

Probably should have commands below before update/upgrade but only hind sight is 20/20

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: I do not see any errors in your output. And I do not expect any problems if you reboot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my Broadcomm Wireless drivers do not play well with latest Ubuntu 14.04 updates.

I just removed debian packages bcmwl-kernel-source and dkms.

The packages might very well run fine, but apt-get upgrade hangs, and I don't want to to deal with contantly freezing updates.

Now I can run 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' and smooth sailing.

Comment: Why Debian packages? Why not Ubuntu packages from the usual repositories?